# c# delegate and abstract class

Tags: c#

I currently have 2 concrete methods in 2 abstract classes.  One class contains the current method, while the other contains the legacy method.  E.g.

```
// Class #1
public abstract class ClassCurrent<T> : BaseClass<T> where T : BaseNode, new()
{
    public List<T> GetAllRootNodes(int i)
    {
      //some code
    }
}

// Class #2
public abstract class MyClassLegacy<T> : BaseClass<T> where T : BaseNode, new()
{
    public List<T> GetAllLeafNodes(int j)
    {
      //some code
    }
}
```

I want the corresponding method to run in their relative scenarios in the app.  I'm planning to write a delegate to handle this.  The idea is that I can just call the delegate and write logic in it to handle which method to call depending on which class/project it is called from (at least thats what I think delegates are for and how they are used).

However, I have some questions on that topic (after some googling):

1) Is it possible to have a delegate that knows the 2 (or more) methods that reside in different classes?
2) Is it possible to make a delegate that spawns off abstract classes (like from the above code)?  (My guess is a no, since delegates create concrete implementation of the passed-in classes)
3) I tried to write a delegate for the above code.  But I'm being technically challenged:

```
    public delegate List<BaseNode> GetAllNodesDelegate(int k);
    GetAllNodesDelegate del = new GetAllNodesDelegate(ClassCurrent<BaseNode>.GetAllRootNodes);
```

I got the following error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, property ClassCurrent<BaseNode>.GetAllRootNodes(int)
```

I might have misunderstood something... but if I have to manually declare a delegate at the calling class, AND to pass in the function manually as above, then I'm starting to question whether delegate is a good way to handle my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way you're attempting to use delegates (constructing them with `new`, declaring a named delegate type) suggests that you're using C# 1. If you're actually using C# 3, it's much easier than that.

Firstly, your delegate type:

```
public delegate List<BaseNode> GetAllNodesDelegate(int k);
```

Already exists. It's just:

```
Func<int, List<BaseNode>>
```

So you don't need to declare your own version of it.

Secondly, you should think of a delegate as being like an interface with only one method in it, and you can "implement" it on the fly, without having to write a named class. Just write a lambda, or assign a method name directly.

```
Func<int, List<BaseNode>> getNodesFromInt;

// just assign a compatible method directly
getNodesFromInt = DoSomethingWithArgAndReturnList;

// or bind extra arguments to an incompatible method:
getNodesFromInt = arg => MakeList(arg, "anotherArgument");

// or write the whole thing specially:
getNodesFromInt = arg =>
    {
        var result = new List<BaseNode>();
        result.Add(new BaseNode());
        return result;
    };
```

A lambda is of the form `(arguments) => { body; }`. The arguments are comma-separated. If there's only one, you can omit the parentheses. If it takes no parameters, put a pair of empty parentheses: `()`. If the body is only one statement long, you can omit the braces. If it's just a single expression, you can omit the braces and the `return` keyword. In the body, you can refer to practically any variables and methods from the enclosing scope (apart from `ref`/`out` parameters to the enclosing method).

There's almost never any need to use `new` to create a delegate instance. And rarely a need to declare custom delegate types. Use `Func` for delegates that return a value and `Action` for delegates that return `void`.

Whenever the thing you need to pass around is like an object with one method (whether an interface or a class), then use a delegate instead, and you'll be able to avoid a lot of mess.

In particular, avoid defining interfaces with one method. It will just mean that instead of being able to write a lambda to implement that method, you'll have to declare a separate named class for each different implementation, with the pattern:

```
class Impl : IOneMethod
{
    // a bunch of fields

    public Impl(a bunch of parameters)
    {
        // assign all the parameters to their fields
    }

    public void TheOneMethod()
    {
        // make use of the fields
    }
}
```

A lambda effectively does all that for you, eliminating such mechanical patterns from your code. You just say:

```
() => /* same code as in TheOneMethod */
```

It also has the advantage that you can update variables in the enclosing scope, because you can refer directly to them (instead of working with values copied into fields of a class). Sometimes this can be a disadvantage, if you don't want to modify the values.

Comment: If you want the delegate to map to a specific method if it is type `ClassCurrent` (the `GetAllRootNodes`) and another method if it is of type `MyClassLegacy` (the `GetAllLeaveNodes`) then you would have to know the type of the instance. Whereas if it shares a common interface no need to know the type just that it implement the given interface. The code for setting up the delegate for each type would either contain an if to check the type or a method that take the specific type as an argument for each allowed type.

Comment: @Cornelius - what do you think a delegate is? It sounds like you think it's the same as a function pointer in C.

Comment: delegates are more powerful than function pointers being that they are "first-class methods" and have closure, but this would only allow you to pass them polymorphically and will not eliminate the complexity of setting it up as in the above comment.

Comment: What's complicated about writing the name of the target method?

Comment: Nothing if it was the same method on each class and this method was shared in a common interface or base class. But writing the name depending on the type will involve more code. And that code will be similar in size to implementing an interface.
You would have `if (type A) d = instance.B() else if (type B) d = instance.C()` every time you want to set up a delegate for each type. And that would involve runtime type checking not very good OO.

Comment: You may have neglected to mention that using an interface provides the ability to implement dependency injection thus decoupling the behavior from the fields(properties)?
So yes more code needs to be written but it provides more flexibility for future modification or enhancement

Comment: @DaniDev most dependency injection systems support using delegate types to describe services too.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a delegate that is initialized with references to different methods depending on some conditions.

Regarding your questions: 
1) I'm not sure what you mean under "knows". You can pass any method to the delegate, so if you can write method that "knows" about some other methods than you can do a similar delegate.
2) Again, delegates can be created from any method that can be executed. For example if you have an initialized local variable of type `ClassCurrent<T>` you can created delegate for any instance method of type `ClassCurrent<T>`.
3) Delegate can call only the method that actually can be called. I mean that you cannot call `ClassCurrent.GetAllRootNodes` because `GetAllRootNodes` is not a static method, so you need an instance of the `ClassCurrent` to call it.

The delegate can stay in any class that has access to the `ClassCurrent` and `MyClassLegacy`.

For example you can create smth like:

```
class SomeActionAccessor<T>
{
    // Declare delegate and fied of delegate type.
    public delegate T GetAllNodesDelegate(int i);

    private GetAllNodesDelegate getAllNodesDlg;

    // Initilaize delegate field somehow, e.g. in constructor.
    public SomeActionAccessor(GetAllNodesDelegate getAllNodesDlg)
    {
        this.getAllNodesDlg = getAllNodesDlg;
    }

    // Implement the method that calls the delegate.
    public T GetAllNodes(int i)
    {
        return this.getAllNodesDlg(i);
    }
}
```

The delegates can wrap both static and instance method. The only difference is that for creation delegate with instance method you need instance of the class who owns the method.

Comment: Once the delegate is created e.g. public delegate void del(int i), the code stays in a particular class. I was thinking that the delegate needs to stay in the class that has the methods-of-interest or else it won't be able to find them.  Also, I dont get why delegates can create a static method?

Answer (score 1):

Let both `ClassCurrent` and `MyClassLegacy` implement an interface `INodeFetcher`:

```
public interface INodeFetcher<T> { 
    List<T> GetNodes(int k);
}
```

For `ClassCurrent` call the `GetAllRootNodes` method from the interface's implementation and for `MyLegacyClass` the `GetAllLeaveNodes` method.

Comment: If you have one method in your interface, use a delegate instead. You will save yourself a *mountain* of code. A delegate is like a one-method interface, plus a lot of language support that means you don't have to write separate named classes every time you want to implement it. The type you're looking for here is `Func<int, List<T>>`.

Comment: @Daniel but you won't be able to use the delegate polymorphically without declaring it on a common base class or interface and you would still need to set up the delegate which will also require a comparable amount of code.

Comment: See my answer. Setting up a delegate requires far less code than declaring and implementing an interface. Also delegates are indeed polymorphic: the caller just gets a value that they can make a method call via, they are not bound to a specific implementation. It's exactly like a one-method interface, but with far less ceremonial code required to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want a delegate for this? It sounds overly complex. I would just create a method in a new class that you could instansiate when you needed to call you method. This class could be given some context information to help it decide. Then I would implement logic in the new method that would decide whether to call the current method or the legacy method.

Something like this:

```
public class CurrentOrLegacySelector<T>
{

  public CurrentOrLegacySelector(some type that describe context)
  {   
     // .. do something with the context. 
     // The context could be a boolean or something more fancy.
  }

  public List<T> GetNodes(int argument) 
  {
    // Return the result of either current or
    // legacy method based on context information
  }
}
```

This would give you a clean wrapper for the methods that is easy to read and understand.

Comment: I think that solution with delegate is more flexible - you will need less actions to support third such method. On the other hand the third method may not appear in the future :)

Comment: A delegate is not more complicated, it's far simpler.

Answer (score 0):

As a variation of the theme suggested by Rune Grimstad I think you could use the strategy pattern (e.g. 

[Introduction to the GOF Strategy Pattern in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/strategypattern08072006095804am/strategypattern.aspx) ).

This would be especially interesting in the case where you cannot change the LegacyClass (and therefore maybe cannot easily use the "interface approach" suggested by Cornelius) and if you are using dependency injection (DI; [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)). DI would (maybe) let you inject the correct implementation (concrete strategy) in the right place.

Strategy:

```
public interface INodeFetcher<T> { 
    List<T> GetNodes(int k);
}
```

Concrete Strategies:

```
public class CurrentSelector<T> : INodeFetcher<T>
{
    public List<T> GetNodes(int argument) 
    {
    // Return the result "current" method
    }
}

public class LegacySelector<T> : INodeFetcher<T>
{
    public List<T> GetNodes(int argument) 
    {
    // Return the result "legacy" method
    }
}
```

-> Inject/instantiate the correct concrete strategy.

Regards

Comment: But the interface has one method. This is simply a recipe for a lot of unnecessary hand-coding that is eliminated by using a delegate.

Comment: Where am I missing something? By the way you may have noticed that I am not fluent in delegate programming; if you could please be gentle :)

Comment: did you see my answer? I'm not sure what else to add to it... if you are only concerned with how your requirements look today, then you don't really need to organise your code in any particular way. Almost all high-level language features are about simplifying future evolution of your program. So today you may only have two implementations, but what about in the future?

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker - I did see your answer but I fear I do not understand it completely, sorry.
I think my confusion comes from the line `getNodesFromInt = DoSomethingWithArgAndReturnList;`. To use this, `DoSomething...` has to be defined somewhere, right? If so, I do not see the difference between this "somewhere" and the concrete strategy. Both would be (in) a separate class, no?
I see things are different if there are like a gazillion ways I could (in future) want to do something (like in `ArrayList.Sort(...)`. But if there are maybe 5 or 10 ways to do something and I needed to do

Comment: "something" all over my code, would I not need to "implement" (e.g. using a lambda) the delegate every time I need it (even if I do the same thing again as somewhere else in the code)? If I don't want to do this, I can of course put it in a separate class and use this with `getNodesFromInt = DoSomethingWithArgAndReturnList;`-style syntax. But then I am back at sqaure 1...
I hope my elaboration is understandable.